# What rails server should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

I'm currently developing a rails app, based on Redmine, using a multitenancy approach. The app it is intended to be used by lots of users (at least I hope so :)), so it is important that it can handle several requests without compromise its performance. Having this in mind, I'm wondering which rails server would suit my needs best. I'm currently using thin, for memory savings purposes, but I'm afraid it is not the best choice for me... I've used unicorn before and I liked it a lot, but it was consuming a lot of memory and I had to change it to another one, but I've noticed that my app is not as fast as it used to be. Any advises? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you're going into redmine hosting business, I would reconsider. The market is quite populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Passenger with Apache.

[image]

[check here](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/comparisons.html)

Comment: I'm currently using thin + nginx on my production environment (I was using unicorn combined with nginx before), but Passenger with Apache looks like a great option!

Comment: Yes.. its having much speed and taking less memory!

Comment: @ana3ela If my answer is useful, please accept it.

Comment: I think I will give passenger+apache a try! Thank you so much for your help! :)